# IE bug: th:before doesn't get the entire height of the <th> itself

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Inside the th's in my table there is a :before element. This was done to achieve a certain effect with the borders. Chrome etc, render everything perfectly. In IE (checking IE11, but the previous ones have the same effect) the :before element doesn't take up the entire height of the th. 
In the case of having different amount of content in different th's (1 line vs 2 lines), this causes the border to surround only the content of the th but not the entire th and the design breaks.

I've copied the relevant parts to jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/anna_k/krds75fb/

My html:

```
<div class="container">
<TABLE class="table table-bordered table-condensed table_type2">
    <TBODY>
        <TR class="headlineTR">
            <TH>test</TH>
            <TH>test</TH>
            <TH>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test test test test test test test</TH>
             <TH>test</TH>
             <TH>test</TH>
             <TH>test</TH>
         </TR>
         <TR> 
             <TD>test</TD>
             <TD>test</TD>
             <TD>test</TD>
             <TD>test</TD>
             <TD>test</TD>
             <TD>test</TD>
         </TR>
         <TR class="odd">
              <TD>test</TD>
              <TD>test</TD>
              <TD>test</TD>
              <TD>test</TD>
              <TD>test</TD>
              <TD>test</TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
              <TD>test</TD>
              <TD>test</TD>
              <TD>test</TD>
              <TD>test</TD>
              <TD>test</TD>
              <TD>test</TD>
           </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
 table.table tr td {vertical-align: middle;}
 table.table_type2 tr.headlineTR th {background: rgb(175, 214, 228); border-width: 1px 1px medium; border-style: solid solid none; border-color: rgb(179, 214, 228) rgb(179, 214, 228) currentColor; border-image: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold; position: relative; z-index: 10;}
 table.table_type2 tr.headlineTR th::before { border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); border-image: none; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: -1; content: "";}
 table tr.odd td {background-color: rgb(236, 244, 245);}
```

Any help as to what's causing this to break will greatly be appreciated!

Comment: You can set a rather large value `height` to `th::before`, that can sort of fix the issue, but the results may slightly different, and be aware of unwanted scrollbars if the value is really large.

Comment: @Pangloss, thanks, this together with overflow hidden on the th itself solves the left and right borders, which is almost the same... that's probably what I will end up doing if I don't find any other solutions.
But would be nice to find a way to actually force it to be the correct height and solve the bottom border issue as well.